# Is it worth using Rails' built-in Javascript files, or do it from scratch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

For those of you using Rails and a lot of AJAX, what are your thoughts on the built-in functionality for Javascript? What about jquery-rails? Do you go with it? Do you fight against it? Do you start from scratch?

With 3.1 having so many changes when it comes to Javascript, does it make sense to setup your 3.0.7 project in a certain way to make it easier to upgrade later?

Comment: I prefer using [`jQueery`](http://jqueery.com/)

Comment: @Raynos: LOL. I thought was really on the page for a bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my point of view:

- `jquery-rails` just make jQuery (+ UI) your Rails' standard js library
- the only js file made by Rails is `rails.js` and yes it handles all built-in functionalities and does it really well (example: the delete used in the scaffold generator or the ajax submission of forms)
- if you are also talking about rjs, this is really a matter of choice. I'd not recommend it for frontend features (cause it's mainly server side), but I like to use it for admin parts.

There are no huge changes concerning js in Rails 3.1, or at least nothing which would make your previous code fail:

- you still have the choice of your js library
- you'll be able to use the awesome CoffeeScript as a native part of your dev environment, but it's still not mandatory.

Comment: Yes, coffeescript interests me. I worry that I am adding framework/library on top of framework/library, so everything might be overly complex. I hope that's not the case ;) How do you go about separating your javascript files? What about deployment and making sure everything is minified and in 1 file (if that's the correct way to go about it these days)?

Comment: These days I do use Jammit but it would be automatic in Rails 3.1

Comment: Jammit looks pretty cool. How do you deal with dependencies of different javascript files? It doesn't seem like require.js and coffeescript are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I pass on the Rails helpers. The JavaScript Rails produced used to be obtrusive and wiring up your own ajax in application.js is just so easy with jQuery. That said, in Rails 3 it looks like the helpers are unobtrusive so you should be fine either way. I think no matter what option you choose learning CoffeeScript is a good idea.

Comment: If you put everything inside of application.js, wouldn't that end up being pretty large? How do you manage it? I used to use require.js to manage things. What was your approach? I expect my javascript to end up being fairly massive by the time I am done.

Comment: You don't need to keep it all in application.js. You can create layout specific or even view specific js files.

Comment: I know that, but then you are tasked with including multiple javascript files on the same page, and you have to load them in the right order, and all of this stuff... which I don't think is fun to do when it's desirable to put all of your modules/classes/whatever in different files :(

Answer (score 0):

I've formed habits of not touching RJS or any of the Rails JS helpers starting with the 2.x series of releases, mainly because of the obtrusive nature of the Javascript produced.  It makes it very difficult to test without resorting to something like Selenium, which I personally regard as a poor substitution for real testability. I don't use them in 3.x either, but the caveat there is that they've been redesigned to be more unobtrusive, though I'm not sure how really unobtrusive RJS could actually become.  My recommendation would be to avoid it until you've learned the right way of doing things without them, and then start using them if you find that they provide a real benefit without impeding your development process.